# execute code before calling parent constructor in dart

Tags: dart

I'm starting on dart and I want to know if there is any way to execute code before calling the constructor of a parent class.

I have a class that inherits from another and I want to execute code on one of the parameters that I have to pass to the parent class.

this is what i have

```
   MyOption(final List<String> opts,Map<String,dynamic> 
    attrs):super(opts,attrs){
    this.my_default = attrs['my_default'];
   }
```

and this is what i want (python code):

```
def __init__(self, *opts, **attrs):
  self.my_default = attrs.pop('my_default', None)
  super(MyOption, self).__init__(*opts, **attrs)
```

As you can see, I need to delete an element from the list before passing it as a parameter to the constructor of the parent class.

Can it be done in dart?

Comment: Do you control the class from which you are inheriting?

Comment: I'm passing a program from python to dart. Yes, I can change the parent class but I would prefer not to.

Comment: Why can't you do `super(opts, do_some_transform(attrs))`?  Also, in Dart, the [`super` invocation should be last in the initializer list](https://www.reddit.com/r/dartlang/comments/5r02tm/supercall_must_be_last_in_initializer_list/).

Comment: yes , u are right  I solved it following your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyOption(final List<String> opts,Map<String,dynamic> attrs): this.my_default = attrs.remove('my_default'),super(opts,attrs){
    //this.my_default = attrs['my_default'];
  }
```

Thank you.